# Tomcat clientendpoint websocket keeps closing

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, client-server, tomcat7

I have the following `clientendpoint` class for a `websocket` in `tomcat 7.0.53`. It is based off of this example on a website https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-build-java-websocket-applications-using-the-jsr-356-api/

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import javax.websocket.DeploymentException;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;
@ClientEndpoint
public class connect {
    private static ArrayList<Session> sessionList = new ArrayList<Session>();

    public connect(URI endpointURI) throws DeploymentException, IOException
    {
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        container.connectToServer(this, endpointURI);
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException
    {
        sessionList.add(session);
        System.out.println(session.getId());
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("hello");
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException
    {
        for(Session session : sessionList){
            //asynchronous communication
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session){
        sessionList.remove(session);
        System.out.println("here");
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t, Session session){
        System.out.println("tedt");  
    }
}
```

I then have the following code to start the client endpoint

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.websocket.DeploymentException;


public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DeploymentException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        connect connect = new connect(new URI("ws://localhost:8080/example/talk"));
        connect.sendMessage("now");
    }

}
```

The client does successfully connect to the websocket server, however then it gets disconnected right away when I try to send a message or do anything, I know this since the `onError` function is being called when I try to send a message from the `onOpen` function. Why is the `websocket` getting closed immediately after it is connected to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being disconnected because your main thread in your client application is ending. After you send "now", your program simply exits. If you want to do anything else (like wait for a response from the server, for instance), then you'll have to prevent the main thread from exiting. Try something like this at the end of your `main` method:

```
System.in.read();
```

This will cause your process to sit and wait for input from standard input. Simply wait for your test to complete and then press ENTER on the command-line to terminate the client.

You will, of course, want to register a handler for receiving messages back from the server to the client. Right now, you can only send messages from the client to the server.

Comment: Thanks and yes of course about the receiving messages back, just a proof on concept that at least I can communicate with the server.

Comment: I am trying to make this work, I have a server endpoint and but I always get the error of Could not find an implementation class. for the ContainerProvider, I have the javax websocket jar in my build path

Comment: Maybe ask a new question?